# Changing background of page by providing url - jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the background of page using jquery , so i change the css in below format since url is involved the background doesn't change how can i fix this ?

```
$('body').css({
"background":'url("/../../site/images/bg.png")',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$('body').css({
    backgroundImage: 'url(/../../site/images/bg.png)'
});
```